# Catching unique constraint exception in JSF

Tags: java, postgresql, jsf, jboss

I have a column "name" in database with unique constraint. I'm trying to handle database exception, to catch it, and return user friendly message to the user.

Problem is with type of exception. Cause of Exception is

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
```

But when I get exception (top Exception is `javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException`) it can't be recognised as `PSQLException`.

After some research I found that, and tried to se why I can't get "PSQLException" so I put a code like this:

```
//code with saving row to database
} catch (javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException e) {
    try {
        int a = ((PSQLException)TisUtil.getRootError(e)).getErrorCode();
        addMessageWarn("That name already exists");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        addmessageError(ex);
    }
}
```

The goal is to see why Java doesn't catch `PSQLException`.
So, program goes into section with `EJBTransactionRolledbackException`. `GetRootError` method finds a root cause which is `PSQLException`, but it can't cast it.

Exception ex looks like this:

```
ClassCastException", detailMessage: "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException cannot be cast to org.postgresql.util.PSQLException".
```

I'm using Jboss, wildfly 8.0, Persistance 2.0, PostgreSQL.

Comment: its not related to JSF. what is `TisUtil` class? have you checked if its really returning underlying exception?

Comment: TisUtil is class with static methods. getRootError returns a root cause using a e.getCause() in while loop. Yes, I check it, it returns PSQLException.

Comment: Seems a classloader problem, verify that you don't have repeated jdbc driver in your deploy . How you access to the database?

Comment: More notably it seems that two different classloaders each have their own copy of the same class - that is the main reason to get the otherwise weird "cannot cast X.Y.Z to X.Y.Z" exception. Possibly the jar is deployed as both a JBoss module and as part of the application. If so you should research into putting modules on the classpath of a deployed application.

Comment: Yes, I have driver in WildFly, and using it also in a POM.xml with <scope>runtime</scope>. This is because when a had <scope>provided</scope> I had a "class not found" exception.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're probably using JTA or EJB3 transaction management.

This defines a layer on top of JDBC exceptions. You cannot catch the JDBC exceptions, because they're wrapped by the EJB3 exceptions. To learn more, read about EJB3, JTA, and EJB transactions.

You must unwrap and inspect the exceptions, something that Java is notably terrible at. Tools like Apache ExceptionUtils help a lot, as they can walk down an exception tree to find a particular exception class.

There's no guarantee any `PSQLException` is the root; it's possible to have a java socket exception or something as the root and a PSQLException wrapping that.